# How to add endpoints to circle progressbar?

Tags: tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk, tizen-web-app

I would like to use the Circle-Progressbar in Tizen web as answering method for a questionnaire. It is important that the answering scale has poles (or endpoints) like "Low" for 0% and "High" for 100%. is there a possibility to somehow "pull" the beginning and end of the Progressbar apart and add a label to each, containing the mentioned words? It should look similar to that one on the picture below, found on http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7545959/

[image: Scale with enpoint-labels]

Thanks in advance

Comment: A different input method with the same functionality is also appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm just posting how I solved this exactly, in case someone runs into the same situation.

I imported the JQuery Plugin "roundSlider" from here: http://roundsliderui.com/ into the Tizen Project. (via .zip file and the import-feature)

I chose the "pie" shape for my needs and added labels to the ends. Now it looks like this: [image: Screenshot of Wearable with roundslider]

The value can be put in by turning the bezel or touching the slider at the desired position.

Thanks to Soundar for the great help and thanks to Armaan for providing the hint into the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried different types of 'progress' UI components offered by TAU ( Tizen Advanced UI ) framework?

https://developer.tizen.org/development/api-references/web-application?redirect=/dev-guide/3.0.0/org.tizen.web.apireference/html/ui_fw_api/Wearable_UIComponents/wearable_circleprogressbar.htm

https://developer.tizen.org/development/api-references/web-application?redirect=/dev-guide/3.0.0/org.tizen.web.apireference/html/ui_fw_api/Wearable_UIComponents/wearable_progress.htm

https://developer.tizen.org/development/api-references/web-application?redirect=/dev-guide/3.0.0/org.tizen.web.apireference/html/ui_fw_api/Wearable_UIComponents/wearable_processing.htm

If these can't fulfill your requirement, keep in mind in web application development, you can use all the html css UI libraries/frameworks available online. Just have to add some tricks for circular wearable display.

Seems you need one 'input type: range '/slider and two circular buttons with labels. Two buttons would increase / decrease slider's val. You may check out the TAU Slider.

Comment: Thank you once again! It was still a bit of work, but the hint with the slider made the deal. I posted my solution as an answer, so that also others can take advantage from it.